# In current flow, do electrons propagate simultaneously or one after another?

Tags: electric-current

## If we have 2 atoms (atom 'A', atom 'B') each with their own electron (A: 'Ea', B: 'Eb'):

When Ea jumps from A -> B, simultaneously, is Eb in the process of jumping from B -> 'C'?

or does Eb only jump to C after Ea has arrived at B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The electrons in a conductor (metal) are highly mobile, i.e., they are not tightly bound to the nuclei of their atoms, so that they are essentially shared by all the neighboring nuclei of the atoms in the conductor, forming an electron "cloud",

When an electric field is applied to a conductor, all of the electrons essentially simultaneously experience a force that causes them to collectively "drift". or move in a direction opposite the direction of the field (the direction of an field, by convention, being the direction of the force that a positive charge would experience if placed in the field).

There is no specific sequence, or "jumping", of individual electrons. In other words the sequence of movements of individual electrons are random from electron to electron. But the overall movement of the electrons, collectively, are in the same direction and result in the current.

Hope this helps.

Comment: To confirm I understood what you said: in current, electrons flow (in the majority) independently like a water molecule down a stream. They don't travel similar to a mechanical wave like sound?

Comment: A mechanical wave, like sound, does not involve net movement of molecules in the direction of the wave. Molecules do not have net movement in the direction of the mechanical  wave, energy moves in the direction of the wave. A closer analogy is the independent movement of water molecules down a stream.  But it's not quite analogous, because individual water molecules may move the total distance down the stream, but  individual electrons may not move the total distance. The drift velocity of electrons is very low.

Answer (score 1):

In normal conductors and semiconductors charge carriers are quasi free. An electric field causes them to acquire a drift velocity limited by scattering, leading to behaviour according to Ohm's law. There are however other forms of conductivity where electrons perform hopping motion. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_transport_mechanisms